# getting an exception in jBoss server as java.lang.RuntimeException: Error unmarshalling file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, jboss, integration

I have 2 instance in one instance my application is running fine but in another instance its giving an exception .I am working on red-hat with jboss-5.1.0.GA version.

the Exception is as follow

```
19:59:05,178 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: /opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/tmp/deploy
19:59:05,771 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error unmarshalling file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.xml.BootstrapParser.parse(BootstrapParser.java:60)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:123)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:177)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:119)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.xml.BootstrapParser.parse(BootstrapParser.java:53)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml
        at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:105)
        at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:112)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:173)
        ... 7 more
19:59:05,870 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
19:59:05,896 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
Shutdown complete
Halting VM
bash-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/conf/bootstrap.xml
```

Also, be aware that you are using a version which is really old.

Comment: this file is really existed there in the jboss server.